# react-leaflet.js: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: leaflet, maps, react-leaflet

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

```
<MapContainer center={position} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
    <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    />
    <Marker position={position}>
        <Popup>
            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
        </Popup>
    </Marker>
</MapContainer>
```

from leaflet-src.js:144

I am trying to render the map from the example given in https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-popup-marker/ site but getting this error.

Comment: Could you post your code that created this error?

Comment: And next time you post something to a forum, select the title so that anyone that wants to help you can figure out from it what the problem is. Title like `Can anyone please provide the solution for the below issue?` is the worst you can choose, because every single question here is posted wanting someone to provide a solution.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.